# How to use rawQuery() in android

Tags: sql, android

I have a sql query like this

```
String loadFav = "SELECT _id, title, name, favorite FROM table1 where favorite= 1 " 
                     + "UNION ALL" 
                     + "SELECT _id, title, name, favorite FROM table2 where favorite= 1"
                     ;

    Cursor mCursor = mSQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(loadFav, null);
```

I got an error when run this query. Is it right structure? Can someone help me?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us exactly which error you get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always troubleshoot by looking at the SQL string -- not the code that builds the SQL string!

```
SELECT _id, title, name, favorite FROM table1 where favorite= 1 UNION ALLSELECT _id, title, name, favorite FROM table2 where favorite= 1
```

You need a space between `ALL` and the second `SELECT`.

Comment: Oh! I break my query because it too long on the screen, and I forgot about the "space"! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate that Java doesn't permit string literals to span lines.  It leads to this common type of mistake.