# How to implement a union query using the SqliteDatabase query method

Tags: android

I am developing an application when i retrieve a data from an sqlite database using rawQuery method because the query is a UNION query  and the data is displayed on a listview . I would like to use a query method because i would also like to implement a content provider to handle the data retrieved from the database.
Is there any way someone can implement a union query using the query method.

I would only like to know of the structure since the query is already working using the rawQuery method how do i structure it using a query method

Comment: You can override `query()` in your provider where you can use `rawQuery()`, see tutorials how to implement custom `content provider`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following methods:

```
public String buildUnionQuery (String[] subQueries, String sortOrder, String limit)

public String buildQuery (String[] projectionIn, String selection, String groupBy, String having, String sortOrder, String limit)
```

For SQL queries for Union.

Comment: this two methods return a string with the sql queries how do i implement the queries to retrieve data do i use the rawQuery method

Comment: Oooh! Where are those methods? I can't see them in the ````android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
```` class. @user1534409 I am running a 'raw' UNION query under a content provider/cursor loader set-up just fine. If you were wondering whether ````rawQuery````s played well with this approach then the answer is "Yes, it's fine". :)

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html

Comment: Sweet. +1 :) - I think that's the best we're going to get @user1534409

Comment: @OceanLife maybe you could help me with a sample code of how you did that

Comment: Sure. We'll have a chat since this is off the original topic of this question. I created this room... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14618/android-using-a-union-with-a-content-provider

Comment: i must at least 20 reputation to be able to chat i wasn't getting that so i couldn't reply thanks anyway it was a big help

Answer (score 2):

check the below links

http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html

[How to use rawQuery() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617280/how-to-use-rawquery-in-android)

Comment: Hi i already have the query working using the rawQuery method i would like to stop using this method and use a query method what i would like to know is how i would structure a union query using the SqliteDatabase Query method

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question, take a look at my complete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41104321/5219866).

TL;DR: I think it doesn't currently exist any way to use a query instead of rawquery when you want to do a UNION query.